# How to open a msg file and edit the receiver with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

How to open an Outlook mailitem saved as a .msg file, to edit and send it with Excel VBA?

I know there is a lot of code missing but I have tried a lot of open methods without success.

I must use the .msg file.

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()

    'Send msg

    Dim path As String
    Dim msgFile As String

    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path + "\"

    file = path & "test.msg"

    'here I want to edit the receiver(To) of the msg File then send it
    'but I don't know how

    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "someone@whatever.com"
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
'Send msg

Dim path As String
Dim msgFile As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path + "\"

file = path & "test.msg"

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.mailitem
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(file)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Application.User

    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate`.